# Basic subsets question - need to prove that sets contain each other

Tags: real-analysis

Defined are three sets:

A={(x,y): |x|+|y|<1}

B={(x,y): √x²+y²<1}

C={(x,y): max{|x|,|y|}<1}

Sketch the groups on the xy plane. Prove that A⊂B⊂C.

Now, i've sketched A and B, but i'm having trouble with understanding how to sketch C, and on how to start the proof. I'd love some guidelines or directions on how to think about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Under which operation are these sets groups?

Comment: $C$ is the square with vertices $(-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1),(1,1)$. For $A \subset $B$ square the inequality in $A$.

Comment: What do you mean? maybe "groups" is a bad choice of words, since this is translated...

Comment: The word 'group' is misleading, these should be called 'sets'.

Comment: @KaboMurphy, |x|,|y|<1, so the set does not include the "boundries" of the square. Is that right? If so, isn't this the same sketch as of A?

Comment: @Berci, thank you. Edited the post

Comment: @Zappa I meant the open square with those verticies. SOrry that I omitted 'open'.

Comment: Thanks. For squaring the A Inequality, i get (x+y)^2<1. How does that help me prove that A is a subset of B?

Comment: I understand. So, since |x|+|y|<1⇒(|x|+|y|)²<|x|+|y|<1⇒A⊂B. Is this a good way of putting it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $C$ is the set of those $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ such that both $\lvert x\rvert$ and $\lvert y\rvert$ are smaller than $1$. In other words, it is the open square whose vertices are $(1,1)$, $(1,-1)$, $(-1,1)$, and $(-1,-1)$.

In order to prove that $A\subset B$, you can do this: if $(x,y)\in A$, then $\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert<1$ and therefore$$\bigl(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert\bigr)^2<1.$$But this is equivalent to the assertion that$$x^2+y^2+2\lvert xy\rvert<1.$$So, $x^2+y^2\leqslant x^2+y^2+2\lvert xy\rvert<1$. In other words, $(x,y)\in B$.

And if $(x,y)\in B$, then $x^2+y^2<1$. So, each of the numbers $x^2$ and $y^2$ is smaller than $1$. But this is equivalent to the assertion that $\lvert x\rvert,\lvert y\rvert<1$. In other words, $(x,y)\in C$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can write {(x,y): max{|x|,|y|}<1} as {(x,y): |x|<1, |y|<1} because max{|x|,|y|}<1 means that both of them must be less than 1 (if you had ">" instead of "<", it would have been enough if one of them was greater than one, and if you had min instead of max, it would have been enough if one of them was less than one.
And if you had max and ">" you would have had to set both of them greater than 1).
So the graph looks like a square of lenght 2, centred at 0,0 and with 2 sides parallel to the x-axis and the other two  parallel to the y-axis.
I hope i made no mistakes :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).